# subclipse - Sudden error about too old SVN client

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I use Easyeclipse for PHP with the Subclipse plugin for a long time without any problem.
This morning I committed my project without any problem. This afternoon I try to commit it again and it gives this error, which concerns only a subfolder.

```
Unsupported working copy format
svn: This client is too old to work with working copy
'My subfolder'; please get a newer Subversion client
```

I found several questions where the solution was an update of the client, like the error suggests. But in my case, I didn't change any configuration nor installed anything.

I fear that some files got corrupted.
It could have happened during a manual copy-paste process on my local copy, but I have no indication for this.

Is there a way to know for sure if the problem is with the server side or with the client side.

What are possible steps to restore the situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the client side, server is not contacted at this stage. Your local repository checkout might have been silently upgraded by another svn client you use. Or it might also be damaged and Subclipse errorneously reports it as an upgrade it doesn't understand.

If you don't want to upgrade Subclipse, your only way is to do a fresh checkout from server, and copy over your changes from this upgraded repository.

Comment: A fresh checkout: This means, I have to delete all folders and recreate them from the server ?

Comment: If you have any uncommited work there, back it up first. And then yes, recreate.

Comment: Finally, I made a backup, restored yesterdays backup and manually copied today changes. Fortunately there were not too many.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer if there have been many changes you may use the way pointed out in the below answer which deleting .svn folders and copying in to " fresh checkout" let the windows do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means you used another SVN client that was a newer version and upgraded the working copy to a newer format.  Subclipse has versions that support all versions of Subversion.  Most likely you need to install Subclipse 1.10.x which contains support for the SVN 1.8 working copy format.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Once you upgrade Subclipse to the right version it will immediately work again.  Your existing working copy ought to still be fine.

Comment: After all I think this was  the cause. Probably my collegue touched it with a newer version of Tortoise.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I move eclipse workspace place to another then problem is occured. For solving problem I checkout project form the svn repo. Then in old project I clean all svn files. (simple search .svn and delete ) then I copy the content to the just checkedout one my changes become visible and my project is up to date. This method can be applied for other annoying errors. Hope help someone